# Autoscroll property of TableLayoutPanel is not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayout

I wanted to add rows dynamically in `TableLayoutPanel` with in a fixed area on GUI. So, if the number of records increases then I want a vertical scroll bar that will help user to see more records. For this purpose, I set Property`AutoScroll = true;` but it is not working.

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
c.Text = "Han";
tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1; this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c, 0, 0);
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your code from the comments in another question , you seem to be adding rowstyles on every row, try adding your rows without  adding  styles or add one style first then add all the rows,.

```
  tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c2);
tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 200;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: I had to use different styles for every row, so not adding styles was not an option. Adding a row without style at the end solved the problem though

Answer (score 5):

Thus you didn't post your code, I can't say what you are doing wrong. But this is the way you should add controls to your table layout panel:

```
tableLayoutPanel.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Count;
YourCountrol control = new YourControl();
// setup your control properties
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(control);
// scroll to the bottom to see just added control
tableLayoutPanel.AutoScrollPosition = 
    new Point(0, tableLayoutPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum);
```

Of course you should have `tableLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true`

BTW to avoid annoying horizontal scroll bar, you should add right padding to your table layout panel:

```
tableLayoutPanel.Padding = 
     new Padding(0, 0, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0);
```

UPDATE `AutoSize` should be disabled for tableLayoutPanel. Otherwise scroll will not appear - table layout panel will grow instead.

Comment: this is my code and it is still not working:
`CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
c.Text = "Han";
tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c, 0, 0);
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 0);`

Comment: `this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;` you are setting row count to one. That's the problem. Also set auto scroll to true in designer.

Comment: I also set auto-scroll = true in Designer Properties and also removed the line `this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;` but still not working

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad what about row count? Have you fixed that part?  You should set appropriate row count.

Comment: yes I replaced it with your code 
`tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Count;`
in my code

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad use my code, just replace `YourControl` with `CheckBox`

Comment: I also tried this still not working I cant only see the last record added the older records can't be seen now due to the small size of tablyelayoutpanel still no scroll bar appears

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad looks like you have set `AutoSize = true` to your table layout panel. Auto size should be disabled.

Comment: @lazeberezovsky `AutoSize = false`. Where I can send you screen shots of my code and ouput? Do you have facebook?

Comment: @lazeberezovsky kindly tell me where I can send you the screen short of output?

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad add you code and screenshot to the question

Comment: Note: In Visual Studio 2010, after putting "SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth" as Padding value, when returning to the design page, it was changed to value of 16 both there and in the Designer.cs.